# How to Access a Variable in Multiple Methods

Tags: c#

I have function openport, which opens a serial port. But when I need to use the serial port in other functions, I get an error that the name does not exist in the current context. I tried to change private to public, but it's still not working. For example:

```
public void openportbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort seriovyport = new SerialPort(COMtb.Text);
    seriovyport.Open();
    //here I crate serial port with COM from text box and open it

}

//but if i want to use it anywhere else
public void closeportbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seriovyport.Close(); //I get error
}
```

How can I make the serial port public?

(sorry for my English | my first post on this forum)

Comment: Your English appears good, better than some English speakers. :) Easy to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a class-level field to reference the port instead:

```
private SerialPort seriovyport;

public void openportbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seriovyport = new SerialPort(COMtb.Text);
    seriovyport.Open();
}

public void closeportbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seriovyport.Close();
}
```

Comment: To add to the answer: what you have is a "_local variable_". It is visible only within the method. What you want is an "_instance variable_" or "class member". It will be visible throughout the class.

Comment: And FYI, it's not that you needed to make the variable public. You needed to make it _visible_. In C# terms, you needed to increase the _scope_ of the variable.